# how to concatenate parameters with variable of body in react native

Tags: react-native

i have to concatenate the variable with parameters to get the json response

```
body: `category_id=208&sort_by=low`
```

i have to pass like this token value in vaiagtion between screens but while concatenating the value it shows token is an templatestring

```
let Token = this.params.token;
let Token = 209;
body:`category_id=`+{Token}+`&sort_by=low`,
```

this is the error response:-

```
error response: TypeError: {
                    Token: Token
                  } is not a function. (In '{
                    Token: Token
                  }(_templateObject())', '{
                    Token: Token
                  }' is an instance of Object)
```

so how should i concatenate the parameters with variable ?

Comment: Use a template literal:
````category_id=${Token}&sort_by=low````, make sure you encapsulate the string with back ticks or the ${varName} is not honored.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might be mixing the syntax for string concatenation and template literals.

You can concatenate the strings: `'category_id=' + Token + '&sort_by=low'`

Or you can use template literals (introduced in ES6): `` `category_id=${Token}&sort_by=low` ``

You can read more about template literals [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Hope that helps!